# how to access javascript object from a function?

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I have:

```
var test = {};
test.Data1 = {
    ...JSON objects here...
}; 
test.Data2 = {
    ...JSON objects here...
};
and so on...
```

I usually access these json objects followed by a set of calls by:

```
this.scope.testData = test['Data1'];
```

However, may data for test is getting larger so i just wanted to pass whatever data i want to a function and do the processing like:

```
this.scope.setupData = function(data)
{
    var fData = test[data]; // is this line correct? 
    ...
    ...
    return fData;

};
```

but it's not working. I'm getting :Cannot set property "fData" of undefined to "[object Object]" ...  I'm new to javaScript, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's the exact wording of the error? Sure seems like you're leaving out a bunch of important information.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to  use `data` as a property name... but `data` is an Object.

Comment: How do you call `setupData` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the scope inside `this.scope.setupData`. To access the variables relate to `this.scope` you need to use `this` again:

```
/**
 * At current scope, "this" refers to some object
 * Let's say the object is named "parent"
 *
 * "this" contains a property: "scope"
 */
this.scope.setupData = function(data)
{
    /**
     * At current scope, "this" refers to "parent.scope"
     *
     * "this" contains "setupData" and "testData"
     */
    var fData = this.testData[data]; // is this line correct? 
    ...
    ...
    return fData;
};
```